# When I pause my game scene in unity editor by keyboard ctrl+shift+P，‘Assertion failed ...’ appears in console window

Tags: unity, gui

I am using Unity 2017.2.0f3. When I pause my game scene by use mouse click on pause button & play it frame by frame, it works OK. Instead, pause by use ctrl+shift+P keys down, an error will play once in console window at the time I press frame by frame button.

```
Assertion failed: Assertion failed on expression: '!dest.m_MultiFrameGUIState.m_NamedKeyControlList'
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

This would happens even in the new created empty scene!

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: This sounds like an editor bug to log with the makers of the software.

Comment: Didn't read carefully enough to see you already had the full error message - my mistake.

Comment: Actually, my poor English writing skill made too many grammar mistakes in my expression to read it closely. That's not yours, Pikalek.   :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a [known error](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/assertion-failed-error-is-thrown-after-pausing-the-game-with-a-shortcut-key-and-stepping-one-frame).

The error report doesn't specifically include Unity 2017.2.0f3, but the patterns seems to fit. Since the error is not reproduced in 2018.1.0a4 and up, the best recommendation I can give is to upgrade / update to that version or later.

Here's the full error report:

> **Assertion failed error is thrown after pausing the game with a
>   shortcut key and stepping one frame**
>
> Steps to reproduce:
>
> 1. Create a new project
> 2. Enter Playmode
> 3. Press Ctrl+Shift+P or Cmd+Shift+P at the same time
> 4. Press "Step" button
>
> --Assertion failed error occurs
>
> Error: "Assertion failed: Assertion failed on expression: 
>   '!dest.m_MultiFrameGUIState.m_NamedKeyControlList'UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32,
>   IntPtr)"
>
> Reproducible with: 2017.2.0b5, 2017.2.1f1, 2017.3.0f2, 2018.1.0a3  Not
>   Reproducible with: 2017.1.2p4, 2017.2.0a4  Regression introduced in
>   2017.2.0a4
>
> Is not reproducible with 2018.1.0a4, a5, a6, a7

Comment: While annoying,  upgrading/waiting for new versions is the "solution". I had this problem with 5.x and it disappeared on its own with some of the later 5. versions.

Comment: Thank you so much, Pikalek!  I'll upgrade Unity to the bug fixed version.